# synchronizing access to almost identical vectors

Tags: c++, multithreading, vector

**Scenario:**
I have two almost identical vectors. They function like a double buffer to serve a single writer and multiple readers. One vector will be read by a thread group and the other vector will be written to by a single thread. After the writer thread finishes its updates, it will `swap()` the two vectors. This way, the readers can continue reading while the writer prepares the next `frame` and the writer can keep writing away without worrying about the readers.

**Question:**
If the sizes of the two vectors are guaranteed to be the same during the execution of the `swap`, is it safe to not use any locking mechanism when doing the swap? If its not, then what would be the dieal way of making sure that the `swap` is safe without too much overhead on the writer thread?

Comment: You need a locking mechanism regardless of the vectors' size. When the writer is finished with writing to its vector and needs to switch, it must wait until any reader that is reading the read vector finishes. I'm not sure what the relationship is between readers and writer. Do all readers have to read the ouput of the writer or just one of them is sufficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not safe. Consider that even swapping two values is not a safe operation. You would need to use a mutex for this operation. Hopefully, swapping is a relatively low cost operation (even if your vectors are of different length), so protecting the swap should be OK.

Keep in mind that swapping invalidates any references to the content of a vector, which may impact the design of your readers.